# OWA seems to ignore display:none style

Tags: html, css, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-web-app

I am experiencing a problem with Outlook Web app. I build a HTML string in Dynamics CRM email form and have included a span element with display:none style. However, the text is visible in OWA. It was visible in Gmail too, but when I included !important attribute, it disappeared. Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What selector are you using to apply CSS property display:none to it?

Try using more specific selector.

Comment: I use span with inline css. What would be more specific selector?

Comment: Same problem here. Thought I'd solved a preheader problem with `<span style="display:none !important;">` until I looked at it in OWA.  A load of unwanted text right at the top in black Times New Roman.  Lovely.  Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: `<span style='color:white; display:none !important;'>` is what I ended up with.